Was the guilt of Jesus being crucified laid only on those present at Jesus trial?
While reading Acts 2, I was drawn to verses 5, 14, 22-24, and 36. I was also drawn to Acts 4:27. These verses highlighted that the "Israelites" were guilty of Jesus's death. With this in mind, I'd love help understanding if Acts 2:22 is a scripture that should be applied to everyone today or only to those present during the time of Jesus's trial, i.e. the Israelites?
If it applies to the Israelites of that time, this does not remove the fact that Christ dying for our sins is the only way anyone can have the opportunity of eternal life. Romans 6:23 shows that the gift of eternal life, brought through Christ life and death, was just that - a gift freely given to those who embrace following in the steps of Christ (John 3:1-5 & 10:17-18, Acts 5:28, Luke 11:29-32, 1 John 2:5-6).  I would truly appreciate feedback based on understanding of the Greek/Hebrew used. I've recently realised how we can easily miss the meaning of Jesus teaching when we don't understand the original words used and the culture it was spoken to.

Acts 22-23 clearly teaches that Jesus' death was part of God's predestined plan. The "Israelites" (and of course the apostles were also Israelites) were merely God's instruments in accomplishing His will:

22 “Fellow Israelites, listen to what I have to say: Jesus of
Nazareth, a man attested to you by God with deeds of power... 23 this man, handed over to you according to the
definite plan and foreknowledge of God, you crucified and killed by
the hands of those outside the law.

In 2:14 Peter addresses not only his “fellow Jews" but also "all who live in Jerusalem." Vs. 36 affixes no blame but simply declares that Jesus had been resurrected and made "Christ" by God, after being crucified by "you," apparently referring back to "fellow Israelites."  But once again all of this was part of God's plan.
Acts 4:27 addresses God, saying:

27 “For in this city, in fact, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, with the
gentiles and the peoples of Israel, gathered together against your
holy servant Jesus, whom you anointed, 28 to do whatever your hand
and your plan had predestined to take place.

Conclusion: Taken as a whole, these verses teach that God intended Jesus to die an early death from the beginning, and that both Jews and Gentiles were involved in this predestined plan.

The answer to, "Who killed Jesus?" is very simply answered by several verses that say Jesus died for the sins of the whole world:

Isa 53:6 - ... and the LORD has laid upon Him the iniquity of us all.
1 John 2:2 - He Himself is the atoning sacrifice for our sins, and not only for ours but also for the sins of the whole world.
John 1:29, “Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world.”
Rom 5:8, 10, “… while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. … if, while were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him by the death of His Son, …”
1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”

Thus, Jesus died as much for the sins of those who executed Him as for everyone else's sin.  Every sinner is, in part, responsible for the death of Jesus.  Unfortunately, some will reject this gracious offer of eternal (and free) salvation.

Jesus' statement questions whether we should place the blame of Jesus' crucifixion on anyone:

For this reason the Father loves me, because I lay down my life that I may take it up again.  No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord.
(John 10:17–18, ESV2016)

Also guilt passing down from parent to child no longer exists in the new covenant.

In those days, they shall no longer say, “Parents have eaten sour grapes and children’s teeth are blunted.” But every one shall die for his own sins: whosoever eats sour grapes, his teeth shall be blunted.
(Jer. 31:29–30, JPS1985)


Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it. How do you reconcile this with Acts 4:27 and Luke 23:34?

That is obviously true - but the fact remains that if no one had sinned, Jesus would not have volunteered to die.  Thus, sinners still bare responsibility for Jesus' death as its ultimate cause.

@ Dottard  But not their children or decedents.

@PerryWebb Can you elaborate on your statement?

Jer. 31:29–30 The new covenant eliminated guilt passing down to decedents..
